# Displaying tex content in HTML5 app

Tags: javascript, html, tex, mathjax

I need to display TeX content in a div. As far as I understood MathJax will be slow for tex files bigger then one page. So I decided to make HTML from TeX on server with `htlatex`. The problem is that some are printed as image and inserted in html. So here are my questions:

1. What way of images for dynamicaly generated HTML is better? I'm afraid putting them into folder will take a lot of disk space.
2. Is there an easy way to generate MathML from tex (so that I will not need to think about previous question)
3. Maybe there's an other more easy solution for my problem?

**UPD.** And have I understood correctly that MathJax is not to be used here?

Comment: `I'm afraid putting them into folder will take a lot of disk space.` -- Then dynamically generate them each time you render the page, and delete them after the page is rendered.

Comment: [[disclaimer: I'm part of the MathJax team]] While it's true that MathJax might not be optimal for very long documents (say, >>10 pages), this amount of content is never filling the screen at once. The amount usually exposed on a single screen is, in my experience, never a problem for MathJax performance. I would test how loading content on the fly performs for you (and maybe pre-render a few pages to make it smoother).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer two of your questions:

1. Depending on the server-side technology you use, you might have no other choice except to put all the generated image files into a folder. You could write a job that regularly deletes older images to save disk space.
2. There are a few tools that can convert TeX to MathML, for example [TtM (TeX to MathML)](http://hutchinson.belmont.ma.us/tth/mml/) or [TeX4ht](https://www.tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn.html).